# (Nativescript) copy file from bundle to documents directory

Tags: nativescript

Is there a way to copy a file from anywhere within the source app folder to the documents directory of a device? I've been looking at the file-system plugin documentation but couldn't find anything on this topic.

Answer (score 2):

Well looking through the [cookbook](https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/file-system) docs, it seems you can create a reference to the devices documents folder like this:

```
var documents = fs.knownFolders.documents();
```

You can then get the file from your app with something like this(?). Where path is a reference to the file bundled in your app:

```
var myFile = fs.File.fromPath(path);
```

So you could then do something like:

```
// Writing text to the file.
myFile.readText()
        .then(function (content) {
            // Successfully read the file's content.
        documents.writeText(content)
           .then(function () {
              // Succeeded writing to the file.
           }, function (error) {
              // Failed to write to the file.
           });
        }, function (error) {
            // Failed to read from the file.
        });
```

Comment: Right, but this approach only describes how to copy the contents of a text file and what I'm after is being able to copy a binary or, ideally, a folder (I know I wasn't specific enough in the original question, sorry about that). I've already figured out how to locate my source file/folder in the app bundle and how to find the destination path. The missing piece is how to get the binary/folder from path A to path B.

Comment: Ahh I see. Have you tried that approach anyway, as if you interpret the binary as a string (will be nonsense) and then write it back into a file with the correct file ending, it might still be readable as a binary when picked up by the system?

Comment: Sorry! I've been swamped with work on a different project and haven't had a chance to check this yet. Will update as soon as I've looked into this. Thanks!